# Whose mask is this?

Tags: merchandise

This phone charm was part of a lootanime crate. Whose mask is it?

[image: Mask]

Comment: Reppin' A&M in the background there

Comment: It looks similar to the masks the [Anbu Black Ops](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Anbu) in Naruto use. though i don't know if a mask like that actually appears in the series

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Nerdspan](http://www.nerdspan.co) says:

> This month’s phone charm accessorizes well with the shirt and the watch, as like both of those wearable items, the color scheme is also white, red, and black. On the reverse side of the Loot Anime poster, we learn that this is in the shape of a “broken kitsune mask” that belongs to the Loot Anime mascot, Yume.

[image: Yume]